# Div always on top

Tags: html, position, css-float, fixed

i want a always visible div on the right of my page.
I called it "#sidebar". Its floated right on the body of my page.
The problem is when the page is not maximized  or in some little monitors the floated div moves the main page (#container). any ideas to solve that? thx

Answer (score 2):

yes,

remove float and add:

```
#sidebar{ position:absolute; right:5px;}
```

and if you specify the width of sidebar in % it won't move the rest of your content, i guess,

but it's allways easier if you post your code, can you post you CSS??

Comment: you are a totally css guru, ty

Comment: it is customery after a useful answer, to check it off.